# Proper way for autoloading in Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, autoload, jloader

I'm trying to make my news module modification working with Joomla 4. My module is calling custom fields and I use this autoloader below to make it work in Joomla 4. Can you tell me what is the proper way to use autoloader on Joomla 4 instead of using this legacy one?

```
JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should still work in 4.0 but will break in 5.0. You are advised to use fully qualified class names. Remove `JLoader::register()` call and instead add a `use` statement:

```
use Joomla\Component\Fields\Administrator\Helper\FieldsHelper;
```